# Android fragment : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TestFragment{431d000} not attached to a context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-context

I get the following error in my fragment reported in my appcenter console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TestFragment{431d000} not attached to a context.
```

With the following stacktrace:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext Fragment.java:696
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources Fragment.java:760
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString Fragment.java:782
com.corp.mycompany.data.ui.TestFragment$fetchData$1.onFailure TestFragment.kt:511
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:92
android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:883
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:100
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:224
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:7520
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:539
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:950
```

This refers to the following lines:

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<FetchDataResponse>, t: Throwable) {
    Log.e(tagLabel, "fetchAssetsOnFloor() - onFailure() Could not fetch data: ", t)
    errorLabel.text = getString(R.string.no_data_available)
}
```

Does it means that I need to replace:

```
errorLabel.text = getString(R.string.no_data_available)
```

by

```
errorLabel.text = activity?.getString(R.string.no_data_available)
```

What is the difference between these 2 lines ?

Comment: It looks like `onFailure` callback is triggered after the fragment has been detached from activity, due to navigating back for example.
So when fragment's `getString` is called, it tries to get Resources instance using fragment's context using `requireContext` method that throws these `IllegalStateException`
Your second option will get resource only if the fragment is still attached to the activity

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to prevent this behaviour ?

Comment: Do I need to replace all call from `getString(..)` to `activity?.getString(...)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think using this second option won't help, since fragment's view is already destroyed at that time, so the safest option would be
`errorLabel?.setText(context?.getString(R.string.no_data_available))`, since `errorLabel` could be null as well

Comment: Or `errorLabel?.text = context?.getString(R.string.no_data_available))` if you prefer property access syntax :)